# Half Gauge (Meio Velocimetro) para Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Preciso construir um Gauge de meio-circulo usando `Xamarin forms`, os controles pagos não atendem pois só possuem Gauges Circulares. É possível até exibir como meio-circulo, porém desperdiça parte essencial da tela.
Como posso construir um controle assim ? Alguém conhece algum código pronto para isso?

Estou procurando algo como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

**Aqui estão dois exemplos de semi-circulares:**

http://www.infragistics.com/products/xamarin-forms/gauges/radial-gauge
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/circular-gauge/shapes
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]